# Print TeX from argument as a simple string

Tags: luatex, verbatim

I have a macro that is like this:

```
\newcommand{\note}[1]{
    \thenoteid
    \dosomething{#1}
}
```

That macro is being used in scenarios like this:

```
Aenean eu leo quam. \note{Pellue ornare \somelatex semcinia quam} venenatis vestibulum.
```

Now I'd like to adjust the `\note` macro to be something like this:

```
\newcommand{\note}[1]{
    \href{\thenoteid}{\printasstring{#1}}
    \dosomething{#1}
}
```

Where the output would do it's normal thing at `\dosomething{#1}` but would wrap `\thenoteid` in a link that would have the raw latex like this: `Pellue ornare \somelatex semcinia quam` as the actual `href`.

**Note**

I'm aware that this would result in URLs that aren't correct, but I'm planning to view my PDF in a custom built viewer that will disable the normal function of links and parse the "url" for another purpose.

**Things I've Tried**

`\begin{verbatim}` but this resulted in errors, it seems like that doesn't work inside of an `\href` call. Maybe there's an "inline" version of this?

I did a bunch of google searching, and tried many code snippets that didn't really make sense to me, but seemed like they were answering similar requests. Like `\typeout`, `\expandafter`, probably others...

Comment: Maybe `\href{\thenoteid}{\detokenize{#1}}`?

Comment: @Marijn that is what I was looking for! THANKS!!

Comment: @Marijn Your comment, simple as it is, deserves to be posted as an answer. And the OP should accept it.

Comment: @rallg this is surely a duplicate, instead of answering I'll see if I can find a good target question to close this one.

Comment: Also related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538299/text-display-on-hyperref-package/538303